# How do I browse and discover the REST APIs exposed by Cloud Endpoints after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I discover the apis exposed by Cloud Endpoints when I deploy my project to google app engine, to say myapp.appspot.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the APIs Explorer: `https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`, which will list the APIs served by your application (including the discovery API itself). You can experiment with the APIs in the Explorer as well.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the discovery and explorer? I might not want to expose the service definition for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

An other great testing method is the following, which can be used both at the deployed API and the one running on you local host:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://yourAppName.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/yourAPIName/v1/

Remember to change the "base = https://..." to http://localhost:8888.... (or whatever port you are using) when using it on localhost and you must ofcourse replace yourAppName and yourAPIName with the correct entries for your project